# Reference or pivot points in SVG?

Tags: user-interface, svg

Can I have "reference" or "pivot" points i.e. points, that are not rendered, but whcih I can find in SVG and determine their location?

I would like to draw several SVGs in the same place to animate button state change, like "pressed", "normal", "disabled" etc. But my SVGs don't have the same outer rectangles, because images can be shifted, shadow can appear etc. So I would like to mark one or two points in SVGs as "pivot" at design time to make them coincide in different states.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can save the point as a var in JavaScript {x,y}

Comment: Use visibility: hidden; perhaps?

Comment: It would be nice to have an example, but it looks to me it would be much simpler to have all the objects in a single `svg` and then show or hide them with `javascript`. This way, every object is in the same coordinate space and no reference points are necessary.